# Wordpress: Post Format single-loop.php using get_template_part

Tags: php, wordpress

I have set up to use post formats gallery and video in addition to the standard. I am editing the loop-single.php to give it different layouts for each post format, but I'm to include get_template_part for each post format.

This is what I have:

```
<?php
/**
 * The loop that displays a single post.
 *
 * The loop displays the posts and the post content.  See
 * http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop to understand it and
 * http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags to understand
 * the tags used in it.
 *
 * This can be overridden in child themes with loop-single.php.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Ten
 * @since Twenty Ten 1.2
 */
?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


<?php

    if ( has_post_format( 'gallery' )) {
      // code to display the gallery format post here

      get_template_part( 'news' 'gallery' ); // News Gallery Template (news-gallery.php) 

    } else if (has_post_format('video')) {
       // stuff to display the video format post here

        get_template_part( 'news' 'video' ); // News Gallery Template (news-video.php) 

    }else {
       // code to display the normal format post here

        get_template_part( 'news' 'standard' ); // News Gallery Template (news-standard.php) 

    }

    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>


?>
```

It is coming up with an error when I'm testing:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /home/judddev/public_html/pitch/wp-content/themes/pitch/loop-single.php on line 26

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: get_template_part( 'news' 'gallery' ); // News Gallery Template (news-gallery.php)  Apprently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add comma between

get_template_part( 'news', 'gallery' );

Comment: New error comes up Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /public_html/pitch/wp-content/themes/pitch/loop-single.php on line 40, which is <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

Comment: <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

Comment: Thanks. It wasn't this in the end. i had the <?php endwhile; ?> in the wrong place. I'll post the answer hold on.

Comment: ok i my answer is is useful for you then just accept my answer with clicking on the right arrow. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add a comma:

```
get_template_part( 'news', 'gallery' );
                 here ___^
```

and also in the oher calls to `get_template_part`

Comment: New error comes up Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /public_html/pitch/wp-content/themes/pitch/loop-single.php on line 40, which is <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/**
 * The loop that displays a single post.
 *
 * The loop displays the posts and the post content.  See
 * http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop to understand it and
 * http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags to understand
 * the tags used in it.
 *
 * This can be overridden in child themes with loop-single.php.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Ten
 * @since Twenty Ten 1.2
 */
?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


<?php

    if ( has_post_format( 'gallery' )) {
      // code to display the gallery format post here

      get_template_part( 'news', 'gallery' ); // News Gallery Template (news-gallery.php) 

    } else if (has_post_format('video')) {
       // stuff to display the video format post here

        get_template_part( 'news', 'video' ); // News Gallery Template (news-video.php) 

    }else {
       // code to display the normal format post here

        get_template_part( 'news', 'standard' ); // News Gallery Template (news-standard.php) 

    }

    ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Just need to switch these around from this:

```
 <?php endwhile; ?>


    ?>
```

to this

```
?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
```